# swift 4 pickerview with images

Tags: swift, image, uipickerview

I am trying to get images to show up in the pickerview instead of text.
I am seeing ? and no images. I know the images are correct as I am using them in another view.

I tried to follow some other stack overflow posts but to no avail.
like this one: [How can I get images to appear in UI PickerView Component in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769246/how-can-i-get-images-to-appear-in-ui-pickerview-component-in-swift)

[image]

code:

```
import UIKit

class ShuffleViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var shufflePicker: UIPickerView!
var pickerData: [String] = [String]()

let images = [UIImage(named:"Acceptance"),
              UIImage(named: "loveimage"),
              UIImage(named: "gratimage"),
              UIImage(named: "successsmall"),
              UIImage(named: "pos"),
              UIImage(named: "rel"),
              UIImage(named: "weal"),
              UIImage(named: "heal2"),
              UIImage(named: "confiden")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    shufflePicker.delegate = self
    shufflePicker.dataSource = self

}

func numberOfComponents(in shufflePicker: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
return 6
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> UIImage? {

return images[row]
}
```

I'm no sure what to do as I am fairly new to Xcode and swift

Comment: You can't change the signature of data source and delegate methods. `titleForRow` returns `String`, not `UIImage?`. And please look at the answer to the question you linked. The answer does not use `titleForRow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you can use this Method

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {


        let myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 61))


        myImageView.image = pickerDataSource[row]


        return myImageView

    }
```

Comment: You don't need the extra `UIView`. You can simply return the `UIImageView`.

Comment: yes i get you , just in case hw want to add complex row with image and other UI element @rmaddy